# Postgres + macOS High Sierra: Release ports and uninstall on a Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker

When I started to work with Postgresql on my Mac I tried different things such as Postgres.app , postgresql.org installer etc. Now whenever I start my Mac it seems a Postgres database is running (I can connect to it with postico)

As I want to switch to Docker now, I somehow want to uninstall Postgres on my Mac and release the ports. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Open the activity monitor and checks which process is running posgres and uninstall it.

Comment: That helped, thank you!